# Transform YTD values into period (without date field)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have financial data stored as YTD values per month and would like to write a query/view to have these as periodic values.

Sample source table:

[image]

Looking around I did figure out a way, by pivoting 2 YTD periods and making their difference for each periodic value separately.

My below example is the calculation of February 2018 (TIMEID 20180200) periodic value.

```
Select * FROM
(Select '2018_02' as PERIOD, CATEGORY,DATASRC,ENTITY,GROUPS,Subtables as CC,ACCOUNT, Coalesce(Ytd,0) - Coalesce(PrYtd,0) as MTD
FROM(
Select CATEGORY,DATASRC,ENTITY,GROUPS,SUBTABLES,ACCOUNT, [20180200] as Ytd, [20180100] as PrYtd
FROM 
(Select ACCOUNT,CATEGORY, DATASRC, ENTITY, Rezidor_5.dbo.tblFactFinance.INTCO, Sum(SIGNEDDATA) as Amount, SUBTABLES, GROUPS, TIMEID, CURRENCY
 From (Rezidor_5.dbo.tblFactFinance INNER JOIN Rezidor_5.dbo.mbrAccount ON Rezidor_5.dbo.tblFactFinance.ACCOUNT = Rezidor_5.dbo.mbrAccount.ID) INNER JOIN Rezidor_5.dbo.mbrEntity ON Rezidor_5.dbo.tblFactFINANCE.ENTITY = Rezidor_5.dbo.mbrEntity.ID
 WHERE  LEFT(TIMEID,4) = '2018' AND CATEGORY In ('ACTUAL') AND Rezidor_5.dbo.tblFactFinance.INTCO ='TPTOP' AND ACCTYPE in ('INC', 'EXP') AND ENTITY = 'EDIZR' AND DATASRC in ('INPUT','INPUT_LADJ') and GROUPS = 'LC'
GROUP BY ACCOUNT,CATEGORY, DATASRC, ENTITY, Rezidor_5.dbo.tblFactFinance.INTCO, SUBTABLES, GROUPS, TIMEID,CURRENCY) t1
PIVOT
(SUM(Amount) FOR TIMEID in ([20180100],[20180200])) as t2) as t3)as t4
WHERE MTD <> 0
```

My issue is that I would like to do this dynamically, avoiding to hard code the periods. I did have a go at using a variable, but found out the Pivot element 
can not deal with a variable.

Even better would be a more elegant technique I can apply to entire table.

Thanks for any input that can put me on the right track.

@D-Shih the expected result:
[image]

Table Time 
[image]

Comment: Could you provide your expect result?

Comment: Assuming your `TIMEID` field is always in `YYYYMM00` format, what is stopping you using `cast(left(TIMEID,7) + '1' as date)` to get a date you can use in your query for grouping, calculations, etc?

Comment: @iamdave utter lack of skill with a hint of stubbornness is what is usually stopping me, but thanks for the suggestion. If I understand correctly is to add a date field and use that as basis for the calculation. Will check the posts using a date field.

Comment: @D-Shih I added a sample at the bottom of the original post

Comment: This looks more like a cumulative total problem than a pivot problem.You should maybe research lag function.BTW timeid looks fine for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PIVOT` doesn't help you here.  Simply use a `JOIN` and pass the values as parameters:

```
with t as (
      select ACCOUNT, CATEGORY, DATASRC, ENTITY,
             ff.INTCO, sum(SIGNEDDATA) as Amount, 
             SUBTABLES, GROUPS, TIMEID, CURRENCY
      from Rezidor_5.dbo.tblFactFinance ff INNER JOIN
           Rezidor_5.dbo.mbrAccount a
           ON ff.ACCOUNT = a.mbrAccount.ID INNER JOIN
           Rezidor_5.dbo.mbrEntity e
           ON ff.ENTITY = e.ID
     where CATEGORY In ('ACTUAL') AND
           ff.INTCO ='TPTOP' AND
           ACCTYPE in ('INC', 'EXP') AND
           ENTITY = 'EDIZR' AND
           DATASRC in ('INPUT','INPUT_LADJ') AND
           GROUPS = 'LC'
     group by timeid, ACCOUNT, CATEGORY, DATASRC, ENTITY,
              ff.INTCO, 
              SUBTABLES, GROUPS, TIMEID, CURRENCY
    )
select 
from (select t.*
      from t
      where timeid = @timeid1
     ) t1 full outer join
     (select t.*
      from t
      where timeid = @timeid2
     )
     on . . . ;
```

I am a little unclear on what the `join` conditions should be exactly -- one of the columns or all of them?  But the idea is much simpler -- a join between the times you want to compare.

Comment: Hi, I started from a similar join, but the issue is that this requires a record for every period which is not the case for my total data set. If there is no data for one period in the middle of 2 periods with data the calculation will be wrong.  This is what I solved with the pivot as it puts a zero in this case. -->Coalesce(Ytd,0) - Coalesce(PrYtd,0) as MTD

Comment: @WimF . . . This is using a full outer join, so that is not an issue.

Comment: Thanks, i managed to make it work for me on this set of data using a variable for the period. I guess the easiest way i to do this for every month and union the results?

Comment: @WimF . . . You might want to ask another question with simplified data if you have more than two time periods.  This question is specifically about 2 ("by pivoting 2 YTD periods").  I would recommend simplifying the query for such a question.

Answer (score 1):

From your sample data and expected result you seem to want to calculate with previous value, so you don't need to use pivot, you can try to use [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to get previous value then calculation.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   ACCOUNT varchar(50),
   CATEGORY varchar(50),
   DATASRC varchar(50),
   ENTITY varchar(50),
   INTCO varchar(50),
   SIGNEDDATA int,
   source int,
   SUBTABLES varchar(50),
   TIMEID varchar(50),
   GROUPS varchar(50)
);

insert into t values ('TDEC','ACTUAL','INPUT','BRUZT','TPTOP',100,0,'CA','20180100','EUR')
insert into t values ('TDEC','ACTUAL','INPUT','BRUZT','TPTOP',400,0,'CA','20180200','EUR')
insert into t values ('TDEC','ACTUAL','INPUT','BRUZT','TPTOP',600,0,'CA','20180300','EUR')
```

**Query 1**:

```
select 
    ACCOUNT,
    CATEGORY,
    DATASRC,
    ENTITY,
    INTCO,
    (SIGNEDDATA - LAG(SIGNEDDATA,1,0) OVER(PARTITION BY ACCOUNT,GROUPS ORDER BY TIMEID)) SIGNEDDATA,
    source,
    SUBTABLES,
    TIMEID,
    GROUPS
from T
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1c9d7/3/0)**:

```
| ACCOUNT | CATEGORY | DATASRC | ENTITY | INTCO | SIGNEDDATA | source | SUBTABLES |   TIMEID | GROUPS |
|---------|----------|---------|--------|-------|------------|--------|-----------|----------|--------|
|    TDEC |   ACTUAL |   INPUT |  BRUZT | TPTOP |        100 |      0 |        CA | 20180100 |    EUR |
|    TDEC |   ACTUAL |   INPUT |  BRUZT | TPTOP |        300 |      0 |        CA | 20180200 |    EUR |
|    TDEC |   ACTUAL |   INPUT |  BRUZT | TPTOP |        200 |      0 |        CA | 20180300 |    EUR |
```

**Note**

You can spite your calculate group columns `PARTITION BY` and set columns 
order in `order by`

Comment: Thank you for your idea, yet I see one issue to apply it to my larger data set. It is possible that in my source data there is no record for a certain month (when the YTD value equals zero). However the month after there can be a value again.  For the given example when 20180400 = 0 (so no record) and 20180500 = 500. The periodic value of 20180500 should be 500, but with this technique will result in -100 (500-600)?

Comment: @WimF  Create a derived table of all possible periods (algorithmically, not hard coded) and `left join` from that to your actual data, which will provide at least one row for each period to make the `lag` function work as you require.

Comment: @WimF make a calendar table then `left join` you can edit your question and add some sample data for your example I would a sample and explain for your

Comment: @D-Shih I have added in my Time table in my original post, but haven't been able to figure out how to add the missing periods with a zero value for a sample set by means of a left join.

Answer (score -1):

You can use dynamic SQL (see here for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Dynamic SQL is usually a bad practice and must be avoided